# Why do we echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup/bash"?

Tags: ros, installation, bashrc, ros-kinetic, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi#Setup_ROS_Repositories) guide here specifies the command `$ echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc` to source the `setup.bash` in the `~/.bashrc`. For this reason, the end of my `.bashrc` has been looking like the code snippet below.

```
echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

Why can't we just add a `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` to the `.bashrc` instead of the `echo`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250823/why-do-we-echo-%22source-/opt/ros/kinetic/setup/bash%22?/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2016-12-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This command is done one time only:

echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

Once it is appended to .bashrc everytime you open a new terminal the bash script /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash is run.

You could edit .bashrc in a number of ways to add the line "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" to the end of the .bashrc file, echo is just a handy way to edit .bashrc.

---

Originally posted by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) with karma: 101 on 2016-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-27**:
"could" -> "should".

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2016-12-27**:
So a simple `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` would suffice? I was wondering if there was a particular reason as to why the `echo` was being used.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-27**:
@sharan100: yes.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-27**:
I think you misread the [installation / setup instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#kinetic.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup), as they don't actually tell you to add the `echo "source ..` line to your `.bashrc`.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2016-12-28**:
yeah, I would think so!